# Can't remove Default.png?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, default.png

I had been fooling around with an initial splash screen but decided not to use it.  But now, although I deleted Default.png from Resources, the splash screen still appears in the Simulator when I start the app.

Default.png isn't in the project folder, I close and reopen Xcode, splash screen still there.  Close and reopen Simulator, splash screen still there.  I remove the app from the Simulator, build, and the splash screen is still there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try "Clean All Targets" before rebuilding

Comment: Yup.  Worked. Thank you very much.  That was the fastest correct response that I've ever gotten.  (Will accept as the answer soon.  It says I have to wait 9 more minutes to accept this answer)