# Xcode 4 - removing "Default.png"

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, default.png

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't remove Default.png?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042896/cant-remove-default-png)

I am using Xcode 4, but I am sure the issue does not pertain to this specific IDE.

I have set a "Default.png" using the organizer, but I would like to remove it.

At the time I had already created an image in my project which was no longer being used, instead replaced by the image set in the organizer. I have removed that file, and any "default.png" files from my application (*.app) folders, but the image remains.

How can I get rid of this image?

Comment: Isn't Xcode4 still under NDA?

Comment: Exact duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042896/cant-remove-default-png

Sorry for this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a "clean" of your project.